# checkbox con javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero validar unos checkbox de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero mostrar una imagen referente al texto, es decir:
Si selecciono iluminación que muestre una imágen de iluminación.

tengo este código:

```
var click=['#fila1 input:checked'];
var fila1=['Iluminación','Ventilación','Acceso'];

if ((jQuery(click[0]).val() === fila1[1])) {
alert ('imagen de ventilación');
}


if ((jQuery(click[0]).val() === fila1[1] && jQuery(click[0]).val() === fila1[2])) {
    alert ('imagen de ventilacion y acceso');
}

if ((jQuery(click[0]).val() === fila1[0]) {
    alert ('imagen de iluminación');
}

if (todas las combinaciones) {
    alert ('imagen referente');
}
```

El primer if si funciona, pero el segundo no. ¿alguna solución o recomendación?. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con esta forma puedes obtener todos los checks que tengas, asignarlos a un objeto y poder jugar con sus valores.

```js
// Obtenemos todos los inputs tipo check
let checkboxs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

// Creamos un objeto data con sus valores por defecto
let data = {
  iluminacion: false,
  ventilacion: false,
  acceso: false
}

// Recorremos cada check y le asignamos el evento on change con su respectiva acción
checkboxs.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
      data[this.id] = this.checked
      display_by_data()
  });
})

// función para jugar con el objeto data
function display_by_data() {
  console.log(data);
  // aquí puedes jugar con los valores que tenga data
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='iluminacion'/>
<input type='checkbox' id='ventilacion'/>
<input type='checkbox'id='acceso'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas en la linea

```
if ((jQuery(click[0]).val() === fila1[1] && jQuery(click[0]).val() === fila1[2])) {
```

En ambos casos estas comprobando solo el primero de los checkbox seleccionados **click[0]**.

Te sugiero recorrer **click** en un bucle for, y comprobar cada uno de los valores de los checks seleccionados, para ello puedes crear tres variables booleanas por ejemplo.